# Custom behavior in sigma.js

Tags: javascript, sigma.js

I'm using sigma.js to display a graph that is rather large. When a user double-clicks on a node, I want the camera to zoom in on the node clicked - which, thankfully, works out of the box. However, I also want the graph to be redrawn when a node is double-clicked: I want nearby items to be repositioned with the selected node as the center of gravity, and if there are any nodes with direct edges to the selected node that are outside the visible screen after the zoom, I would like those edges to be shortened so that those items are visible.

- Are there technical terms for either of the two requirements specified? (I'm relatively new to sigma and to JS in general and am unaware of such terms, but if I knew how to verbalize what I'm trying to do it would help me figure this out myself).
- How might I approach fulfilling these requirements in sigma.js?
- Is there another visualization framework that is better suited to my needs?

Answer (score 2):

The **Bind callbacks to events** tutorial on their homepage seems to be a good start: http://sigmajs.org/

> The first thing we need to do is to facilitate the way to retrieve the
>   neighbors of a node. And the best way to do that is to add a method to
>   the graph model. Basically, the graph model provides a public access
>   to the nodes and edges arrays, but it also maintains some more indexes
>   accessible only from its methods, including the index of every
>   neighbors for each node. Then, we just need to bind functions to some
>   events, that will first modify the colors of the nodes and edges, and
>   then refresh the rendering. And it's done!

```
<!-- [...] -->
<div id="sigma-container"></div>
<script src="path/to/sigma.js"></script>
<script src="path/to/sigma.parsers.min.gexf.js"></script>
<script>
  // Add a method to the graph model that returns an
  // object with every neighbors of a node inside:
  sigma.classes.graph.addMethod('neighbors', function(nodeId) {
    var k,
        neighbors = {},
        index = this.allNeighborsIndex[nodeId] || {};

    for (k in index)
      neighbors[k] = this.nodesIndex[k];

    return neighbors;
  });

  sigma.parsers.gexf(
    'path/to/les-miserables.gexf',
    {
      container: 'sigma-container'
    },
    function(s) {
      // We first need to save the original colors of our
      // nodes and edges, like this:
      s.graph.nodes().forEach(function(n) {
        n.originalColor = n.color;
      });
      s.graph.edges().forEach(function(e) {
        e.originalColor = e.color;
      });

      // When a node is clicked, we check for each node
      // if it is a neighbor of the clicked one. If not,
      // we set its color as grey, and else, it takes its
      // original color.
      // We do the same for the edges, and we only keep
      // edges that have both extremities colored.
      s.bind('clickNode', function(e) {
        var nodeId = e.data.node.id,
            toKeep = s.graph.neighbors(nodeId);
        toKeep[nodeId] = e.data.node;

        s.graph.nodes().forEach(function(n) {
          if (toKeep[n.id])
            n.color = n.originalColor;
          else
            n.color = '#eee';
        });

        s.graph.edges().forEach(function(e) {
          if (toKeep[e.source] && toKeep[e.target])
            e.color = e.originalColor;
          else
            e.color = '#eee';
        });

        // Since the data has been modified, we need to
        // call the refresh method to make the colors
        // update effective.
        s.refresh();
      });

      // When the stage is clicked, we just color each
      // node and edge with its original color.
      s.bind('clickStage', function(e) {
        s.graph.nodes().forEach(function(n) {
          n.color = n.originalColor;
        });

        s.graph.edges().forEach(function(e) {
          e.color = e.originalColor;
        });

        // Same as in the previous event:
        s.refresh();
      });
    }
  );
</script>
<!-- [...] -->
```

You basically have to work in the *bind* function :)